# sort a dictionary (or whatever key-value data structure in js) on word_number keys efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I sort a dictionary by key like

```
dict["word_21"] = "Hello Java";
dict["word_22"] = "Hello World";
dict["word_11"] = "Hello Javascript";
```

so that I get

```
dict["word_22"] = "Hello World";
dict["word_21"] = "Hello Java";
dict["word_11"] = "Hello Javascript";
```

There are word_number combinations on indices only and the values are strings. The indices are distinct (no equal values) but could be "undefined" in an error case

Edit: Actually I need the descending and ascending order of it. But the descending order is what I need at the moment.

Comment: You mean a descending sort of the keys, while keeping the correct pairs key-value, don't you?

Comment: exactly. But also reverting the order would be great.

Comment: I think this post is kinda like a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this

```
var sorted = [];
for(var key in dict) {
    sorted[sorted.length] = key;
}
sorted.sort();
```

Sorting `dict` on its keys and writing it back to the object does not make sense to me, but here it goes:

```
function sortOnKeys(dict) {

    var sorted = [];
    for(var key in dict) {
        sorted[sorted.length] = key;
    }
    sorted.sort();

    var tempDict = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        tempDict[sorted[i]] = dict[sorted[i]];
    }

    return tempDict;
}

dict = sortOnKeys(dict);
```

Comment: I think it won't work because the keys have to be split by "_" in order to be sorted in numerical order

Comment: It will not work like this! `dict` stays untouched throughout the process. Afterwards you have an extra array `sorted` that contains the keys in sorted order.

Comment: I got what you meant. But it's not exactly what I need. At the end I need the same dict but sorted by the key. Not only the indices. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: It does not have to be written back to the object. It could also be another object with key-value pairs sorted by the key if it will be more efficient.

Comment: @user1054134: You should have as less objects as possible in memory to make it efficient, espacially on huge data sets. See my solution, which does exactly that.

Comment: what do you mean by:" "does not make sense to me" is just correct.." I need key-value pairs sorted by key and still not loose the corresponding value. why shouldn't that make sense? I just need the result and it doesn't matter if it is the same object or not. the result will be injected into the DOM and will be stored in the localstorage later

Comment: How about: Object.keys(dict).sort()

Answer (score 32):

A javascript object, here used as a key-value-map (called "dictionary"), has no order; ie. you can't sort it.

You would need an array for that, e.g.

```
[
    {id: "word_11", entry:"Hello Javascript"},
    {id: "word_21", entry:"Hello Java"},
    {id: "word_22", entry:"Hello World"},
]
```

then you could [sort that by](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-28) id or by entry. You might use [your id-sort-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921422/sort-javascript-array-with-word-number-values) for that.

---

Or you could use an array of your keys to sort, next to the unsorted data structure. This might be the best (efficient) and simplest approach:

```
var dict = {
    "word_21": "Hello Java",
    "word_22": "Hello World",
    "word_11": "Hello Javascript"
}; // init (like your example)

var keys = Object.keys(dict); // or loop over the object to get the array
// keys will be in any order
keys.sort(); // maybe use custom sort, to change direction use .reverse()
// keys now will be in wanted order

for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) { // now lets iterate in sort order
    var key = keys[i];
    var value = dict[key];
    /* do something with key & value here */
}
```

Comment: The code Amberlamps provided works quite well. Which solution would be more efficient?

Comment: @Amberlamps' code is not guaranteed to work (altough it does in some implementations). You really should use arrays when you need something with an order.

Comment: what do you mean by "some implementations"? of what?

Comment: [Javascript implementations](http://pointedears.de/scripts/test/es-matrix/) only need to follow the [ecmascript standard](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), which defines that object properties [do not have an order](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10587330/1048572).

Comment: ok, but I'm still not quite sure about what you used in your answer. Is it an array? sorry I'm new to javascript. Could you please give me a link to a tutorial to create and access such arrays? I find only associative arrays like assarr["word_11"] = "Hello World";

Comment: OK, sortBy (which is sorting objects in an array by a property of those objects) might be overcomplicated here. Better solution added.

Comment: I actually need an efficient approach. not the easiest one :) but thanks though!

Comment: @user1054134: Yes, it is an array. You might read http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays and http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/

Comment: thanks! so the efficiency of your algorithm is justified by the use of only one object? Then it sorts the keys and returns the sorted keys and values of the object, right?

Comment: yes, it uses one array to store the order of keys and one object (the "dict", which is already there) to store the data, indexed by key.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to sort keys in an object, the following is fine (its a one liner)

```
/**
 * (typescript) returns the given object with keys sorted alphanumerically.
 * @param {T} obj the object to sort
 * @returns {T} the sorted object
 */
 const sort = <T extends object>(obj: T): T => Object.keys(obj).sort()
        .reduce((acc, c) => { acc[c] = obj[c]; return acc }, {}) as T
```

or the same in javascript

```
/**
 * (javascript) returns the given object with keys sorted alphanumerically.
 * @param {T} obj the object to sort
 * @returns {T} the sorted object
 */
 const sort = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).sort()
        .reduce((acc, c) => { acc[c] = obj[c]; return acc }, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

@Amberlamps nice solution works most of the time. But, the OP is correct that there are *splitting issues* with certain keys. The default behavior of sort() in javascript is to use string Unicode code points to determine the order of the elements. For example, the following keys will *not* get sorted correctly using @Amberlamps method:

```
canvas_2_1/15/2018__2:55:20_PM

canvas_24_1/15/2018__2:55:20_PM
```

But we can customize the sort method taking advantage of the fact that sort() accepts an *optional argument* which is a **function** that compares 2 elements of the array.

By customizing the sort logic of the compare function and passing it to the sort() method the keys above get sorted correctly:

```
sorted.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = parseInt(get_between(a, 'canvas_', '_'));
    b = parseInt(get_between(b, 'canvas_', '_'));
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (b > a) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    });
```

In this case I'm using the following get_between method:

```
function get_between(str, char_a, char_b) {
   res = str.split(char_a).pop().split(char_b).shift();
   return(res)
}
```

Th point is, if you have tricky keys (which may or may not be "proper" use of dict) you can adapt the sort function to still sort correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the dictionary type does not have a keys() method, while the Object type does. You can pass the Object.keys() method an iterable and get the keys back as a list which has a .sort() method.

```
Object.keys({r:2,d:2,c:3,p:0})
// returns ["r", "d", "c", "p"]
Object.keys({r:2,d:2,c:3,p:0}).sort()
// returns ["c", "d", "p", "r"]
Object.keys([6,7,8,9])
// returns ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

And finally, let's [jsFiddle the OP's code](http://jsfiddle.net/txcsthy0/1/).

Update: Bergi's answer had too much going on and I totally missed the "good answer" part. I didn't even notice he did the same thing I did in my jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why it is not possible to sort a dictionary, we first need to understand how a dictionary works. Unlike a list which orders its items according to an index, a dictionary stores an item at a location indicated by the hash of its key. Using your example, the value "Hello Java" is stored at "word_21". This process involves using a mathematical function to turn "word_21" into a number that can be used as an address. The benefit to using hash-tables (another name for dictionaries) is that it is really efficient for finding values, because hashing a key is much easier than searching through every element of a list.

To recap, there is no way to reorder a dictionary like you are asking for. The only way to place a value before another value, i.e. changing it's location, is by changing its key. Its better to think of the order as arbitrary, and unpredictable.

While dictionaries are really helpful for quickly accessing values based on keys, you might consider using a different datatype for your situation. Why use numbered keys when you could much more easily use a list's index? If you are looking for a quick way to access dynamically changing values based on keys, use a dict. If you want to quickly access elements based on an index, and sorting, use a list. Although, nowadays you can find ordered dictionaries in most languages that also store the keys in an ordered list for indexing. In JS, I believe this still requires 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this trying to remember my JavaScript syntax.
This is how I solved it maybe it will help someone.

```js
// Unsorted Dictionary
YourDict = {
"A" : "1"
"C" : "3"
"B" : "2"
};

// The object sorting function
let alphabetizeByKey = function (dict) {
   // Init your return object
   let retObj = {};

   // Pull keys into array and use builtin array sort to alphabetize
   let keys = Object.keys(dict).sort();

   // If you want descending add keys.reverse();

   // Now loop through your new alphabetical key array
   // Creating a new entry in your return object (dictionary)
   // And add the value from original dict based on the key
   keys.forEach(k => {
      retObj[k] = dict[k];
   });

   return retObj;
}

// You can pass it in and set it to the sorted value returned from the function
YourDict = alphabetizeByKey(YourDict)
```

This works because...

"A mutable value is one that can be changed without creating an entirely new value. `In JavaScript, objects and arrays are mutable by default`, but primitive values are not — once a primitive value is created, it cannot be changed, although the variable that holds it may be reassigned."
-[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable)